# Two Conditions in a PHP 'if' statement

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement, multiple-conditions

This is probably as simple as it gets, but I'm new to PHP and it's not my forte, so please bear with me! I'm stuck!

I've got a form set up with a yes or no answer as a radio button. If the user clicks `yes` they are presented with two further radio button choices: `a` and `b`. If they had clicked `no` they would have been presented with radio buttons `c` and `d`.

Incidentally, I've got some JavaScript hiding the `a` and `b` DIV and the `c` and `d` DIV until either `yes` or `no` is clicked, just to keep things tidy. The `no` DIV, containing `c` and `d` disappears and is replaced with the `yes` DIV when `yes` is clicked after `no`, and vice versa. That's all working fine.

My issue is with the PHP. It's not likely, but if the user hits `no`, makes a choice, say `d`, then decides to change their answer to `yes`, then selects `a`, the script still returns `d`. I guess this is because `d` is still selected and appears last in the HTML flow.

What I would like my script to do is ignore `c` and `d`, even if they've been selected, if `yes` is selected. Similarly I'd like `a` and `b` to be ignored if `no` is selected.

A HTML looks something like this:

```
<label for="yes_or_no">Yes or No?</label>
  <input type="radio" name="yes_or_no" id="yes" value="yes" />
  <label for="yes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="yes_or_no" id="no" value="no" />
  <label for="no">No</label>

<div id="yes">
  <label for="a_or_b" id="a_or_b">A or B?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="a_or_b" id="a" value="a" />
    <label for="a">A</label>
    <input type="radio" name="a_or_b" id="b" value="b" />
    <label for="b">B</label>
</div>

<div id="no">
  <label for="c_or_d" id="c_or_d">C or D?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="c_or_d" id="c" value="c" />
    <label for="c">C</label>
    <input type="radio" name="c_or_d" id="d" value="d" />
    <label for="d">D</label>
</div>
```

My PHP looks like this but it's not working properly:

```
$yes_or_no = $_REQUEST["yes_or_no"] ;
$a_or_b = $_REQUEST["a_or_b"] ;
$c_or_d = $_REQUEST["c_or_d"] ;

if ($yes_or_no="yes" && $a_or_b!="") $result="$a_or_b";
if ($yes_or_no="no" && $c_or_d!="") $result="$c_or_d";
$feedback = "$result";
```

The variable `$feedback` is then emailed to me.

I hope that makes sense! Thanks for your help!

Martin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `==` for testing equality:

```
if ($yes_or_no == "yes" && $a_or_b != "") $result="$a_or_b";
if ($yes_or_no == "no" && $c_or_d != "") $result="$c_or_d";
```

I'm not sure if that will completely solve your problem, but perhaps it will get you started.

Oh, and you can do `$result = $a_or_b` instead of `$result="$a_or_b"`, but that won't affect anything here.

Comment: This looks to be exactly his problem. In this situation, when you use a single = in an IF statement, you're setting the value of that variable, and it's testing if that variable is not false, so in this situation, the IF statement would always succeed. Using a == would definitely fix it. Additionally, you don't need to put $result in double quotes. $feedback = $result will work just fine.

Comment: @Foxtrot, yes. This is definitely a problem. I just meant I didn't go through and analyze the logic to see if it's actually correct even if the error is fixed. In addition, it's possible that neither `if` returns `true` and `$result` is never set. Is he handling that case? I don't know.

Comment: just made the adjustment to the equals operator and it's working like a charm! I'll get the hang of this PHP lark if it kills me (which is quite possible!). In the meantime, thanks to everyone (@konforce, @Foxtrot, @joey, @lonesomeday, and everyone else) who's helping me out! Martin.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently *setting* the variable `$yes_or_no` to the value in the `if`. Use `==` instead of `=`. One is assignment, the other is comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($yes_or_no="yes" && $a_or_b!="") $result="$a_or_b";
```

The problem is with `$yes_or_no = "yes"`.  That is the [assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), not the [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). It says "set `$yes_or_no` to `yes`, then return `true`" (this isn't exactly it, but it's close).  You want an operator that says "return `true` if `$yes_or_no` is equal to `yes`".

Replace `=` with `==` and your code should work.

(There is another reason your code is broken here -- `=` has lower [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `&&`, whereas `==` has higher precedence, but that isn't the biggest issue.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use js to clear any selection of a and b is no is selected and the same thing for when user selects yes.

Also you have some bugs in your php that others have mentioned.